# Getting _flutter is undefined in flutter web, only in production

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have an error that has been appearing in my last few deploys and I am unable to trace it.
It only happens when I deploy to firebase website, debug works without any issues.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at flutter.js:1:1)
(index):50 Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined
    at (index):50:7
```

This shows up in the browser console.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Trading made easy">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
    content="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="tornmarket">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>Torn Market</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <!-- <script>self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;</script> -->
  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try upgrading your packages, I'm having the same error, but only with expressJS not firebase hosting

Comment: I think the problem with firebase config file, can you show it

Comment: since if you tried to see what is in flutter.js from the browser you can see it's the index,html, so firebase is sending the wrong file to the browser

Comment: any solution?...

Answer (score 26):

Here's a solution that worked for me.

In index.html

**Change this**

```
<base href="/">
```

**To this**

```
<base href="./">
```

Comment: This is a good solution when the index.html is not in the root directory of the php web server.

Comment: It worked for me with clearing the browser's cache.

Comment: This was the fix for me as well. There's a blub at the top of the index.html page where the flutter devs talk about changing this value to make your website work. " If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from." See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: This is a problem if you are using CI/CD. flutter will throw error if you try to do `flutter build web --base-href "./"`. It will say that base-href has to start and end with `/`

Answer (score 6):

You should try to rebuild your application with:

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter build web
```

I tried to delete `build` folder manually, but it didn't work. It's preferable to use `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **index.html** file in *your_project_name/build/web* path and put this script after the body tag :
`<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>`.
If it didn't work so maybe flutter.js is missing from the build directory so clean your project by **flutter clean** in the terminal then build it again
using **flutter build web** after that add the tag I mentioned above. Now deploy your web to the host.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same error many days later finding the complete solution steps

## Step 1

#### Change

```
<script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
```

#### To This

```
<script src="/main.dart.js" defer></script>
```

*Note:* Then After **Stp 2** change  inside of `<body>...</body>`

## Step 2

#### Change

```
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
   </script>
```

#### To This

```
    <script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=1417913520');
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      entrypointUrl: "/main.dart.js",
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing the flutter.js file in the build/web folder

Answer (score 0):

don't know whether below code works or not. try to implement the same and **revert back**. **please change your body tag as below**

```
<body>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and tried with `flutter clean` and `flutter build web` but still facing same issue of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at flutter.js:1:1)
```

or

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.dart.js.js:1:1)
```

## Solution

**Step 1**: clear the build

```
flutter clean
```

**Step 2**: remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from the `web/index.html` file

**Step 3**: Build it now

```
flutter build web
```

It works now

**Note**:

- Without step 2, it's works fine at `Netlify` but not with `Nginx`
- In server, while we call the `index.html`, `flutter.js`/`main.dart.js` try to execute the `HTML` code in `.js` script. It's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Better to use any web server.

Example using python:

```
cd build/web
python -m http.server 8000 // or python3
```

and visit http://localhost:8000 on your browser

Documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release